# linux + why I cant change the passwd

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, passwd

I have redhat 6.x version

I am trying to change the passwd from single user mode but I get the following

```
passwd root
changing password for user root
passwd: permission denied
```

then I try to verify  filesystem is mounted in read/write

```
 mount -o remount,rw /
```

but I get permission denied again  when typing  **passswd root**

please help me to understand why I get permission denied from single user mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files?

```
grep root /etc/passwd /etc/shadow
```

Have you attempted editing /etc/shadow (with nano or vim)? You can [manually remove root's password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700690/how-do-i-completely-remove-root-password), and save.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the kernel booting options, change `ro init=/sysroot/bin/sh` to `rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh` and boot CentOS. When logged in, follow these commands:

```
chroot /sysroot
passwd root
touch /.autorelabel
reboot
```

You now should be able to loggin as root user.

[Source](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/09/reset-forgotten-root-password-centos-7-servers/)